# How to fix Resources$NotFoundException: String resource in Kotlin without context?

Tags: android, string, kotlin

**Android, Kotlin.**

I want to use the `RestApiService` file for requests and send String value from the `strings.xml` file further as like that:

```
fun showPostsInRadius(modelSearchParams: ModelSearch, onResult: (Array<Post>?, Boolean, String?) -> Unit){

    val retrofit = ServiceBuilder.buildService(RestApi::class.java)
    retrofit.showPostsInRadius(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT, modelSearchParams).enqueue(

        object : Callback<Array<ModelSearchResult>> {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Array<ModelSearchResult>>, t: Throwable) {
                onResult(null, false, Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.connection_error_login))
                println(t)
            }
...
```

This line gives error:

```
onResult(null, false, Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.connection_error_login))
```

Error:

```
W/ResourceType: No known package when getting value for resource number 0x7f0f003c
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.jaskierltd.goodtogether, PID: 15205
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0f003c
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:338)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:432)
        at com.jaskierltd.goodtogether.network.RestApiService$showPostsInRadius$1.onFailure(RestApiService.kt:145)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$2.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:79)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

**Should I configure anything related to strings.xml file or should I call this with another method?** None of existing topics helped.

Comment: IMHO, `onResult()` should take the resource ID, which then gets turned into a string at the UI layer (activity/fragment/composable).

Comment: @CommonsWare We can. But R.string.my_text.toString() - this gives an ID. However, we can't use it to show the STRING without context?
Insane. The system knows where the ID EXACTLY is, but we can't use it? How does it possible?

Comment: "However, we can't use it to show the STRING without context?" -- correct. "How does it possible?" -- there is more than one language in this world. Something needs to be able to map, at runtime, based on the user and device, what string to use for a given string resource ID. In Android, that "something" is a `Context`. If you do not like that, you do not need to use string resources. You are welcome to manage your internationalized strings in some other way that is more to your liking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no-one provided any answer how to avoid context, **the only way** is to use `context` or get the `ID` of the `STRING` object and send back.

**Option #1:**

```
// Place anywhere you want to get the String
fun getID(): Int{
   R.string.error_no_location
}

// Use this inside Activity
println(getString(getID()))
```

**Option #2:**

```
fun getID(context: Context){
   println(context.getString(R.string.error_no_location))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can depend on your exact context, but for me, I was getting this Exception while trying to set a String resource in my `ViewModel`.

As @CommonsWare said in a comment above, I tweaked my design slightly so my UI (Composable; I'm using Jetpack) does the conversion from the Int, since Composable functions have access to the `stringResource()` method.

So in my `ViewModel` class (`TextFieldState` is a data class that just holds the text value/hint for my custom text fields):

```
private val _firearmInitialShotCount = mutableStateOf(TextFieldState(
        hint = R.string.enter_firearm_initial_shot_count
    ))
    val firearmInitialShotCount: State<TextFieldState> = _firearmInitialShotCount

data class TextFieldState(
    val text: String = "",
    val hint: Int = 0,
    val isHintVisible: Boolean = true
)
```

Then in my Composable function (`TransparentHintTextField` is just a custom composable that adds a hint to the `BasicTextField`):

```
val initialShotCountState = viewModel.firearmInitialShotCount.value

TransparentHintTextField(
                text = initialShotCountState.text,
                hint = stringResource(id = initialShotCountState.hint),
...
```

Hopefully that helps someone. I know mine is particular to my case, but the idea is to hold the String Resource Int in code and then in the Composable call `stringResource()` on your Int.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you and found to be better to save this kind of string in a Constant.kt file, like `const val CONNECTION_ERROR = "Your error message"`.  I use the strings.xml file for storing strings which populates the layouts.